# DataType property mismatch

Tags: c#, sql

I have a Stock Configuration Application and every stock I have amount of items. Every each item, to show in my GridView I have to add some column to my database View. Here is my code:

```
        EuroPOS_BusinessLayer.Item b = new EuroPOS_BusinessLayer.Item();
        DataTable dt = b.ListViewByID(Convert.ToInt32(grdSearchForItems.DataKeys[grdSearchForItems.SelectedIndex].Values["item_id"]));

        dt.Columns.Add("countedStorage", typeof(Int32));
        dt.Columns.Add("countedStorageText", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("countedQuantity", typeof(Decimal));
        dt.Columns.Add("countedDescription");
        if (!dt.Columns.Contains("PROC"))
            dt.Columns.Add("PROC");

        dt.Rows[0]["countedStorage"] = Convert.ToInt32(ddlItemSelectedStorage.SelectedValue);
        dt.Rows[0]["countedStorageText"] =(ddlItemSelectedStorage.SelectedItem.Text);
        dt.Rows[0]["countedQuantity"] = Convert.ToDecimal(txtItemCountedQuantity.Text);
        dt.Rows[0]["countedDescription"] = txtItemDescription.Text;
        dt.Rows[0]["PROC"] = "INS";

        DataTable _tblItems = (DataTable)ViewState["TblItems"];
        if (_tblItems == null)
        {
            _tblItems = dt;
        }
        else
        {
            DataRow dr = _tblItems.Select("item_id = " + grdSearchForItems.DataKeys[grdSearchForItems.SelectedIndex].Values[0] + " AND countedStorage = " + ddlItemSelectedStorage.SelectedValue).FirstOrDefault();

            if (dr != null)
            {
                dr["countedQuantity"] = txtItemCountedQuantity.Text;
                dr["countedDescription"] = txtItemDescription.Text;

                if (dr.Table.Columns.Contains("IdNumber") && dr["IdNumber"] != DBNull.Value)
                    dr["PROC"] = "UPD";
            }
            else
            {
                _tblItems.Merge(dt);
            }
        }
```

After through tough research, I can not find a solution for that. Can you please help me?

Edit: I tried **table1.Merge(TempTable, True, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)** but does not work!

Answer (score 0):

You have a datatype missmatch:

In one case decimal:

```
dt.Rows[0]["countedQuantity"] = Convert.ToDecimal(txtItemCountedQuantity.Text);
```

And the other string:

```
dr["countedQuantity"] = txtItemCountedQuantity.Text;
```

The view expects one of the two, so stick to the same in both cases.

Comment: <target>.countedStorageText and <source>.countedStorageText  but the error is exactly for this column, sir.